# Sending Push Notification only to development installation using FCM

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have an app with working push notification using FCM and I am able to send test notification from Cloud Messaging option. I have uploaded both production and development APNS certs(I am using old method).

Issue:- 
While using self implementation I could clearly differentiate between Development and Production installation by sending Push to either "`api.sandbox.push.apple.com`" OR " `api.push.apple.com`"

How can I do this on FCM? Send push only to sandbox or only to production (without removing certs)?

The app only uses broadcast push notification and user registration tokens are not managed on server.

Comment: You can use the Topic subscriptions on FCM. You can differentiate production and sandbox by topic name.

Comment: Yes as @FaysalAhmed said topics can solve this problem. But don't forget to unsubscribe the topics.

Comment: Yeah but kind of workaround when we already have different URL atAPN level it should reflect some where in settings

Comment: @MohitKumar we are now dynamically creating topic DEVELOPMENT_<VERSION> so even if it remains subscribed,apps go directly from test flight to prod, next development notification will be ignored.